# Align: one line centered and the next right-justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{align*}
F_{X^2}(x) = P(X^2 \leq x) = P(X \leq \sqrt{x}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{x}) = 
    \sqrt{x}
\\
F_{Y^2}(y) = P(Y^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{y}) =
    F_{Y(\sqrt{y}) - F_{Y}(-\sqrt{y}) = 
\\
\frac{\sqrt{y}- (-1)}{2} - \frac{- \sqrt{y}-(-1)}{2} = \sqrt{y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note I am making two statements, the first of which takes one line, and the second of which takes up two lines. As written, all three lines are right-justified. It would seem that it would make more sense to the reader if the first line were centered, and the third line were right-justified, so that it is clear that it is a continuation of line two. Does anyone have a tip for how to achieve this? Should I make the first line its own block, in other words, use `$$$$` for the first line, and `align` for the second line?

Any other suggestions as to how to make my meaning visually clear are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose two possibilities (I guessed the definition of `\p`)

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\p{P}

\begin{document}
First attempt:
\begin{align*}
F_{X^2}(x) &= \p(X^2 \leq x) = \p(X \leq \sqrt{x}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x}
\\
F_{Y^2}(y) &=
  \!\begin{multlined}[t]
  \p(Y^2 \leq y) = \p(-\sqrt{y} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{y}) =
    F_{Y}(\sqrt{y}) - F_{Y}(-\sqrt{y}) = \\
  \frac{\sqrt{y}- (-1)}{2} - \frac{- \sqrt{y}-(-1)}{2} = \sqrt{y}
  \end{multlined}
\end{align*}

Second attempt:
\begin{align*}
F_{X^2}(x) &= \p(X^2 \leq x) = \p(X \leq \sqrt{x}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x} \\[2ex]
F_{Y^2}(y) &= \p(Y^2 \leq y) = \p(-\sqrt{y} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{y}) \\
           &= F_{Y}(\sqrt{y}) - F_{Y}(-\sqrt{y}) =
  \frac{\sqrt{y}- (-1)}{2} - \frac{- \sqrt{y}-(-1)}{2} = \sqrt{y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I would prefer the second one, actually, that makes the development clearer, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. Is the `\\[2ex]` command part of a broader family of commands?

Comment: @EricAuld -- specifying a dimension in brackets following a double backslash is the "conventional" latex method for indicating that the amount of space indicated is to be added between the line just ended and the next line.  if an `amsmath` environment is in effect, do *not* leave a space before the opening bracket -- there were so many questions about errors when a bracketed *math* expression was input at the beginning of the new line that a trap was put in to allow a space (or eol) to decouple the usual option checking for a "skip" instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that, as an alternative, stacks the rows with different alignments, rather than using the `align` environment.  The space between the rows is controlled, as well.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{l}\stackanchor[3ex]{%
F_{X^2}(x) = P(X^2 \leq x) = P(X \leq \sqrt{x}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{x}) = 
    \sqrt{x}
}{%
\def\stackalignment{r}\stackunder[1.5ex]{%
F_{Y^2}(y) = P(Y^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{y}) =%
    F_Y(\sqrt{y}) - F_{Y}(-\sqrt{y}) %
}{\displaystyle%
= \frac{\sqrt{y}- (-1)}{2} - \frac{- \sqrt{y}-(-1)}{2} = \sqrt{y}%
}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]